# Strange behaviour when saving to SQLITE3 via UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sqlite

Im having problems understanding why my sqlite3 insert command is only saving certain index.rows

Currently when the user selects a particular row on the table the following command begins

```
     NSMutableString * videoString = [self.filteredVideoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSMutableString * imageString = [self.filteredImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSMutableString * titleString = [self.filteredTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString * descriptionString = [self.filteredDescriptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Recent ('name', 'title', 'video', 'image', 'detail' ) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", [self.nameString UTF8String],[titleString UTF8String],[videoString UTF8String],[imageString UTF8String] ,[descriptionString UTF8String],NULL];

    char *err;

    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) !=SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
       // NSAssert(0, @"could not update table");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"table updated");
    }
```

when i NSLOG

```
    NSLog(@"video = %@",videoString);
    NSLog(@"image = %@",imageString);
    NSLog(@"detail = %@",descriptionString);
    NSLog(@"title = %@",titleString);
    NSLog(@"name = %@",self.nameString);
```

all the above returns the correct value.

Im not sure what other information you require for this resolve?

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: Does `sqlite3_exec` return `SQLITE_OK` or not?

Comment: yes.. a small percentage of rows will add the data but not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally advised to not build SQL statements using `stringWithFormat`, but rather to use `?` placeholders. This protects you in case one of the values has an apostrophe in it. It also prevents SQL injection attacks. Thus you should

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO Recent ('name', 'title', 'video', 'image', 'detail' ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"%s: prepare error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [self.nameString UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"%s: bind 1 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [titleString UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"%s: bind 2 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

// repeat for the other parameters

if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"%s: step error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Note, in addition to using `sqlite3_bind_text` functions, whenever I don't receive a successful return code, I'll log `sqlite3_errmsg`, so it will tell me precisely what went wrong. If you don't look at these error messages, you're flying blind.

Comment: By the way, while this is probably the right way to do `sqlite3_xxx` calls, binding values, if you find that this is too much code, you can consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which is a thin Objective-C wrapper around the SQLite C library, which greatly simplifies the process of writing solid SQLite code.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rob.. its now giving me the following error prepare error: out of memory which is probably why it is happening. any ideas on what i need to do in this case i havnt worked with the above before

Comment: @Tom - The infamous "out of memory" message means that the database parameter that you passed has not been opened. (When I first posted my answer, I left a setting of the database to `nil` in there; if you grabbed that line, remove it; see my revised answer.) Just make sure your database is open before you call this code, and pass it the right `db` pointer.

Comment: your an absolute genius. Thank you so much for taking your time out to resolve my problem :) also thanks to iPatel and martin

Answer (score 1):

In Your `Insert` String use `"%@"` instand of `"%s"` for add values.

```
  NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Recent ('name', 'title', 'video', 'image', 'detail' ) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')", [self.nameString UTF8String],[titleString UTF8String],[videoString UTF8String],[imageString UTF8String] ,[descriptionString UTF8String]];
```

And also Remove `NULL` From end Of `Insert` String.

Comment: thanks for your comment iPatel. I did as you say but also removed the utf8String for it to work but it didnt make any difference

Comment: @Tom-in NSString not consider "%s" it accept "%@" and also check my editd answr

Comment: Sorry, but using `%@` format for `[self.nameString UTF8String]` is wrong.

Comment: followed your instructions to the letter but it didnt resolve the issue

Comment: @MartinR-sory but i always work as i put it as answer and its work for me :(

Comment: `[self.nameString UTF8String]` returns a C-String, so you *must* use the `%s` format for that. - Or you use `%@` with `self.nameString`.

Comment: This is Correct Martin... however it dosnt resolve my problem :) any ideas?

Comment: @Tom-remove NULL from end of NSSTring

Comment: @iPatel... this i have done also.. however didnt make a difference :(